# Create special matrix

Tags: matrix

I need to construct special matrix in mathematica which is given in the following image

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Array` command provides a simple way to transform a function into a matrix.

```
n = 6;
η = ConstantArray[1, n+1];
η[[1]] = 2;
a = Array[{i, j} \[Function] UnitStep[i - j] Mod[i - j, 2] 4 (i - 1)/η[[j]], {n+1, n+1}];
a // TeXForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  6 & 0 & 12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 16 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  10 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 24 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 24 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Is this what you are looking for? Zero-based indexing is quite untypical in mathematics...

Comment: Thanks sir, the matrix should be:{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {6, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 16, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 20, 0, 
  20, 0, 0}, {0, 24, 0, 24, 0, 24, 0}}

Comment: Dear, thanks again for fast response, I try to do it:d = Table[
  Which[j == i - 2, 0, j == i - 4, 0, j == i - 6, 0, j == i - 8, 0, 
   j == i - 10, 0, j == i - 12, 0, j == i - 14, 0, j >= i, 0, j == 0, 
   2*i, i > j, 4*i], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}] but this will work till n=14, remember please I,j=0.....n so when n=6 it will be 7x7 .......best regards

Comment: Many thanks Henrik,  I solved my problem...Best regards

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: `SparseArray[]` can also be used: `With[{n = 6}, Normal[SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i > j && OddQ[i - j] :> 4 (i - 1)/(2 - UnitStep[j - 2]), {n + 1, n + 1}]]]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
dij[i_, j_] := If[i < j, 0, Mod[i - j, 2]] 4 i / If[j == 0, 2, 1];
d[n_] := Table[dij[i, j], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
```

The function `d[]` returns a Mathematica matrix as a list of lists as you would expect. For exmaple, the following code returns `True`.

```
d[3] == {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 8, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 12, 0}}
```

A bigger example is the code `d[6] // Column` which returns each matrix row on a different line.

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
{2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} 
{0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
{6, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0} 
{0, 16, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0}
{10, 0, 20, 0, 20, 0, 0} 
{0, 24, 0, 24, 0, 24, 0}
```

Comment: Dear Somos, thank you for your perfect reponse, can I make the output like:{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {6, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 16, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 20, 0, 
  20, 0, 0}, {0, 24, 0, 24, 0, 24, 0}}

Comment: Many thanks Somos, I solved my problem...Best regards